# How to get events emited by internal transactions?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-design

Solidity:

```
contract A{
   event Invoked();
   function invoke() public returns(bool){
      Invoked();
      return true;
   }
}

contract B{
   function B() {
      new A().invoke()
   }
}
```

Javascript:

```
const tx = await B.new()
assert(tx.logs.length == 0)
```

How can I get the events emitted by `A` while processing the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to A, but first you will need the address. Also you can listen to B.

```
contract A{
   event Invoked();
   function invoke() public returns(bool){
      Invoked();
      return true;
   }
}

contract B{
    event Created(address newContract);   
      function createA() public returns(addressCreated, bool invoked)) {
        A a = new A();
        Created(a);
        bool success = a.invoke();
        return (a, success);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I listen to only events emitted during this transaction on A?

Comment: You can listen to events from B to discover the addresses created and then start event listeners for each instance of A. You will end up with multiple listeners for Invoked tuned into to different addresses of A.